# Unable send Postman request when header contains Japanese character

Tags: request, header, postman

**Header field in Postman:**

```
--header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path": "/テスト自動化/test.xlsx"}'
```

**And next to this field has an warning:**

```
value contains non iso 8859 1 characters
```

**I got error response when sending request:**

```
Could not send request
Error: Invalid character in header content ["Dropbox-API-Arg"]
```

Could someone have any idea to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try selecting the text in Postman and right clicking, then select EncodeURIComponent in the context menu

Comment: Thanks bro, i tried you way but i got another error: 
Error in call to API function "files/upload": HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg": could not decode input as JSON

Comment: Did you encode the entire value? Try selecting just the Japanese characters and encoding them so it looks like `{"path": "/%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E5%8C%96/test.xlsx"}`

Comment: Thanks bro again. I've just tried encode selected part and successfully. But i have new problem is a new folder with above path created. No expected path:

-Actual: new path created: /%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E5%8C%96/test.xlsx

-Expected: Should is path "/テスト自動化/test.xlsx"

Comment: What happens when you replace the japanese characters with `\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8\u81ea\u52d5\u5316`? So `{"path": "/\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8\u81ea\u52d5\u5316/test.xlsx"}`

Comment: Perfectly, it worked for me. So could you tell me the way you parse the path from "テスト自動化" into "\u30c6\u30b9\u30c8\u81ea\u52d5\u5316" bro?

Comment: One thing I can think of is to use a pre-request script in Postman to get the value of that header and update it using something like JavaScripts `escape` function, but I'm not sure if there's a better way

Comment: Bro, do you have any idea for sending postman request with data-raw body: {"path": "/テスト自動化/test.xlsx"}. Look like i cannot use the above idea when ecoding